# Not able to get correct output from LLM model - google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am new to work with LLM.
I am trying to use model google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq from hugging face.
Below are the steps Performed:

1)Downloaded model from hugging-face.
2) Created dummy excel & passed dataframe to model.
3) Asked Query to the Model.

My dataframe:

| Tasks | Complexity |
| --- | --- |
| Account Analysis Report | High |
| Specify Ledger Option | Low |

When I ask, "How many task have complexity = 'High'." I receive correct output.

But When I ask,:

```
Show 3 data rows in random manner.
```

I do not receive the correct rows. Some time I receive the Top one row. and sometimes top 4 rows.

```
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Mayan\Downloads\LLM trained.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1')
df = df.astype(str)

print(df)

oracle = pipeline(model="google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq")

#res = oracle(query="How many are tasks have 'Complexity = 'Y''? .", table=df)
res = oracle(query="Show 3 data rows in random manner.", table=df)
print(res)
```

Model should provide me random rows from dataset provided.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need more random answers, right?

So try adjusting model hyperparameters like temperature top-p or top-k and max_new_token_length.

Usually higher temperature provides more random answers and lower temperature provides more accurate answers.
top-p and top-k is for sampling.
max_new_token is for the length of the output token generated.

Try adjusting these parameters you may achieve your result.